# What is the meaning of about here in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

> Love is not *about* sex, going on fancy dates, or showing off. It’s *about* being with a person who makes you happy in a way nobody else can.

What is the meaning of *about* here?

As far as I think It does not mean the same as in this sentence I wrote a book about love (in the topic of love)

It means something else here

Comment: Google search provides: "on the subject of; concerning.
"I was thinking about you"
**synonyms: regarding, concerning, with reference to, referring to, with regard to, with respect to, respecting, relating to, on, touching on, dealing with, relevant to, connected with, in connection with, on the subject of, in the matter of, apropos, re**"

Answer (score 1):

It's a proposition here; means "**concerned or associated with**", "**summarised in**" or "**defined as**".

Thus your sentence:

*Love is **not about** sex, going on fancy dates, or showing off. It’s **about** being with a person who makes you happy in a way nobody else can.*

Could be paraphrased like:

Love is **not** [**only**] **defined as** sex, going on fancy dates, or showing off. It’s [**rather**] **concerned with** being with a person who makes you happy in a way nobody else can.

Source: www.thefreedictionary.com/about (see prepositions 4, a)

*about:*
"*4, a:*
*in reference to; relating to; concerned with: a book about snakes*"